# Group values in one dataframe based on range in columns in another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, range

I have a dataframe:

```
structure(list(PS_position = c(1000L, 1050L, 1100L, 2000L, 3000L, 
4000L, 5000L, 6000L, 7000L, 8000L, 8500L, 9000L, 9050L, 9001L, 
9051L, 9002L, 9052L, 9003L, 9053L, 9004L, 9054L, 9001L, 9051L, 
9002L, 9052L, 9003L, 9053L, 10000L, 9000L, 9200L, 9340L, 9350L, 
9550L, 9560L), Region_ID = c("BRCA", "BRCA", "BRCA", "BRCA", 
"BRCA", "BRCA", "BRCA", "BRCA", "BRCA", "BRCA", "BRCA", "BRCA", 
"BRCA", "BRCA", "BRCA", "BRCA", "BRCA", "BRCA", "BRCA", "BRCA", 
"BRCA", "BRCA", "BRCA", "BRCA", "BRCA", "BRCA", "BRCA", "BRCA", 
"WNT", "WNT", "WNT", "WNT", "WNT", "WNT"), SNP_ID = c(123455L, 
123456L, 123457L, 123458L, 123459L, 123460L, 123461L, 123462L, 
123463L, 123464L, 123465L, 123466L, 123467L, 123468L, 123469L, 
123470L, 123471L, 123472L, 123473L, 123474L, 123475L, 123476L, 
123477L, 123478L, 123479L, 123480L, 123481L, 123482L, 56789L, 
56790L, 56795L, 56796L, 56816L, 56817L), chr_key = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), probe_type = c("preselected", "preselected", "preselected", 
"preselected", "preselected", "preselected", "preselected", "preselected", 
"validated", "validated", "validated", "validated", "validated", 
"validated", "validated", "validated", "unvalidated ", "unvalidated ", 
"unvalidated ", "unvalidated ", "unvalidated ", "unvalidated ", 
"unvalidated ", "unvalidated ", "non_polymorphic", "non_polymorphic", 
"non_polymorphic", "non_polymorphic", "preselected", "preselected", 
"preselected", "unvalidated ", "non_polymorphic", "validated"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -34L))
```

I would like to summarize the rows in the `PS_position` column.

Typically I did something like this:

```
out_df <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = 1, nrow=length(unique(selection$Region_ID)))), c("Region_ID"))
out_df$Region_ID <- unique(unique(selection$Region_ID))
    x <- selection %>% 
  group_by(Region_ID) %>%
  summarise(num_probesets = length(probe_type))

out_df <- merge(out_df, x, by="Region_ID")

y <- df %>% 
  group_by(Region_ID, probe_type) %>%
  summarise(num_probesets = length(probe_type))

y_wide <- spread(y, probe_type, num_probesets)

out_df <- merge(out_df, y_wide, by="Region_ID")
```

This gives the following result:

```
structure(list(Region_ID = c("BRCA", "WNT"), num_probesets = c(28L, 
6L)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

However, `group_by` by `Region_ID` is missing the fact that some values of `PS_position` can occur in both regions based on this data frame. Hence I want to summarize `PS_position` from the range >=`start` and <= `stop` position in the following dataframe:

```
structure(list(region_name = c("BRCA", "WNT"), gene_symbol = c("BRCA", 
"BRCA"), chr = c(1L, 1L), start = c(1000L, 9000L), stop = c(10000L, 
10000L), resolution = c("fixed", "fixed"), genome_build = c("hg38", 
"hg38"), Notes = c(NA, NA), overlap = c("no_overlap", "no_overlap"
), length_of_region = c(9000L, 1000L), length_of_region_plus_flanks = c(10000L, 
2000L), region_probesets = c(50L, 50L), flank_start_left = c(499L, 
8499L), flank_stop_left = c(999L, 8999L), flank_start_right = c(10001L, 
10001L), flank_stop_right = c(10501L, 10501L), flank_length_left = c(500L, 
500L), flank_length_right = c(500L, 500L), flank_probes_right = c(10L, 
10L), flank_probes_left = c(10L, 10L), total_expected_probesets = c(70L, 
70L), critical_error = c(FALSE, FALSE), flank_name_left = c("BRCA_left", 
"WNT_left"), flank_name_right = c("BRCA_right", "WNT_right"), 
    countrgn = c(50L, 50L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

My final output should hence instead look like this:

```
structure(list(Region_ID = c("BRCA", "WNT"), num_probesets = c(34L, 
23L)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: It would help if you provided the desired final output. It's not clear from the code exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: It's hard to offer alternatives that meet your needs when you don't carefully express the problem and state explicitly what would be a better result. Please don't do the newbie thing by replying in comments. Use [edit]

Comment: Ewwww. I like that. In olden days (maybe a year or less ago) putting `[edit]` into a comment would take one to teh SO page that described the editing facilities. Now it drops the user-clicker into a specific edit framework for this page.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the example completely including an example of the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#create a df with just the start and stop variables
start_stop <- df2 %>% 
  select(region_name, start, stop) 

df %>% 
  merge(start_stop) %>% #Cartesian join
  mutate(Region = ifelse(PS_position >= start & PS_position <= stop, region_name, NA)) %>% #assigns a region to each record based on PS_position
  filter(!is.na(Region)) %>% #drop NAs 
  group_by(Region) %>% 
  summarise(num_probesets = n()) %>% #count number of records by Region
  rename(Region_ID = Region) %>% #rename to join later
  ungroup() %>% 
  left_join( #left join with a df that counts the probe_type by Region_ID
    df %>% 
  group_by(Region_ID, probe_type) %>%
  summarise(num = n()) %>% 
  spread(probe_type, num) %>% 
  ungroup()
  )
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. So I want the values based on `min(start)` and `min(stop)` columns in the second dataframe I have output above, not `min(PS_position)` itself.

Comment: Can you explain how the second `dataframe` relates to the first one? Do you want to join the second `dataframe` to the processed output of the first one and get the `min(start)` and `min(stop)` values?

Comment: It has the same `Region_ID` and all `PS_position`s will lie within the `start` / `stop` of the second dataframe per region

Comment: see my edit - if that is what you are looking for, I can add more details.

Comment: Yes, this answer is perfect! Can you please explain it? I also did a bunch of other summary like `max_gap_length <- df %>%
  group_by(Region_ID) %>%
  mutate(Diff = PS_position - lag(PS_position)) %>% 
  na.omit() %>%
  summarise(max_gap_length = max(Diff))` to get `max_gap`, `min_gap`, `avg_gap` to get distance between `PS_position`s (again grouped by `Region_ID`. This solution should help with that as well I think. Thanks!

Comment: One more note, `Region_ID` may not necessarily be just `BRCA` or `WNT`, I will have 100s of region IDs can there be an alternative to `filter(region_name == 'BRCA')` to avoid specific `region_name` filtering

Comment: I edited my answer and it now considers the new information.

Comment: Did you get a chance to review my edits? Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, this answer is perfect. Thanks! Sorry I was unwell yesterday.